# Detect when user temporarily stop typing on UITextField Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am working a crossplatform project, using Xamarin and facing an issue in getting time delay when user is typing on UITextField.

I have a custom popup which does the search product function to add selected product to cart:

User types product code into textview:

[image]

Currently, while user is typing product code, whenever searchCode= 2, app will show indicator right away then starts searching and user just can continuous to type when the search is done.

**I want to optimize this logic: whenever user stop typing for like 1s (delay 1s), app will do the searching.**

Is there any event that detect when user start and stop typing for UITextField?

```
     public class PopupOrderProductViewModel : BasePopupOrderViewModel
            {
                private string _searchCode;
                public string SearchCode
                {
                    get => _searchCode;
                    set
                    {
                        SetProperty(ref _searchCode, value);

                        if (_shouldSearchCodes)
                        {
                        //hiding keyboard then start searching product by code
                          //I want to change it into: app will start searching whenever user stop typing for 1s
                            if ( value.Trim().Length >= 2)
                            {
                                SearchCodes();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ProductCodeItemViewModels = null;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _shouldSearchCodes = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Code in SearchCode function:

```
private async void SearchCodes()
        {
            MasterViewModel.Instance.ShowIndicator();
            var productCodes = await ProductCodeService.SearchProductCode(SearchCode);
            MasterViewModel.Instance.HideIndicator();
            ShouldShowKeyboard = true;

            ProductCodeItemViewModels = productCodes?.Select(k => new ProductCodeItemViewModel(new OrderedProduct
            {
                ProductCode = k
            }, OnItemClicked)).ToList();
        }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITextField.Notifications.ObserveTextFieldTextDidChange` to detect the text change event in UITextField. And I add a `inputCount` property to record the user's input count to control the search event.

In the `SearchCodes` function, if the search count you passed is not equal to the `inputCount`  right now, this means user has input the text in 1 second and it won't execute the code inside the if statement.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    int inputCount = 0;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UITextField textF = new UITextField();
        textF.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
        textF.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 100, 100, 50);
        View.Add(textF);


        var notification = UITextField.Notifications.ObserveTextFieldTextDidChange((sender, args) => {
            /* Access strongly typed args */
            Console.WriteLine("Notification: {0}", args.Notification);

            inputCount++;

            PerformSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("SearchCodes:"), (NSString)(inputCount.ToString()), 2);

        });

    }

    [Export("SearchCodes:")]
    public void SearchCodes(NSString count)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(count) == this.inputCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start search");

            UIAlertView alertV = new UIAlertView("start search", "",null,"ok");
            alertV.Show();
        }
    }
}
```